# What are all the PHP types that can be found inside the PHP's $_POST variable?

Tags: php, post

What can we find in $_POST:

- That $_POST itself is always an associative array
- String values
- More arrays inside $_POST
- **Anything else?**

Two questions come to one's head:

- What encodings can these strings have?
- Is it possible to find in the $_POST array any values besides strings and more arrays? e.g. `is_integer($_POST['name']) === true`

This is relevant for avoiding unnecesary validations in case the type spectrum is limited enough.

Thank you

Comment: $_POST is always an associative array http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: what datatypes and encodings can we find inside the array?

Comment: I believe the encoding depends on what you specified in the HTML doc that sent the data. E.G utf-8. Also, since php uses duck typing you can see ints, floats, or strings that all act like strings. You will need to test for the types. $_POST supports array and single values as far as I know.

Comment: @bassxzero now I edit my question about that it is always an associative array, but can you please state which kind of values the associative array might contain other than more arrays and strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

may be use `var_dump($_POST);` and check whats there ? :)

Is it possible that $_POST is a object or from other data type different than array?
Is it possible that $_POST is a scalar?

> $_POST is an array, inside that array all the elements are scalar (since all the php variables are scalar).

When $_POST is an array:

> Always !

Is it possible to find anything but strings in it?

> yes, if you send a post request using a html form, example form contains an input field named "name", then `$_POST['name'];` contains the value which was in the input field by the time you submitting it.

When $_POST is an array and its values are strings:

> No, $_POST is always an array.

What encodings can we find in these strings?

> http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php

Comment: It would only give information about the specific cases one would produce, so instead answering the original question this answer just gives birth to a new question: how to post data into PHP casted different than string? But that is not what is being looked for.

Comment: '
are you using any php framework ? or you want to know "how to post data into PHP" in pure PHP ?

Comment: I just need to know what to expect in the $_POST variable, to avoid unnecesary validations, like for example `is_array($_POST);` or `is_string($_POST['foo']);` in case we can find anything but strings inside the $_POST array.

Comment: $_POST is an array, it may contains elements with strings or another arrays.
so is_array($_POST); will be always true and is_string($_POST['foo']); might be true if foo is string only.

Comment: Are you certain that $_POST can contain elements like integers, floats, booleans? (Please ignore ducktyping since strings are still strings and nothing else independently from how they are interpreted in the code because the code itself can interpretate them with the !== operator)

Comment: yeah, elements in $_POST array is either string or another array.